# How to add aspx file and store in a webserver using asp.net in web application

Tags: asp.net

We are currently creating a web application that needs to have a module that will accept a file webpage/code behind) store the file in a web server. configure a hyper link that in a menu that will direct to the webpage.

the scenario goes like this, we have a master page, and there are lots of developer that will develops different modules, so the master webpage will be the one responsible in loading the develop modules on run time.

any idea how to make this kind of web application?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this might be a good lead for you from a previous SO question:

[ASP.NET WebForms Plugin Architecture Ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726450/asp-net-webforms-application-with-pluginable-architecture-problem)